# Click event fires an increasingly number of times

Tags: javascript, svg

So I am trying to build a svg editor. For this functionality I am trying to highlight the selected rectangle by drawing smaller rectangles in each of its corners, using the `onClick` event. But each time I click on a rect, the event fires multiple times, and each time i click on it again, the event fires many more times than before. I attached the code, but the `endDraw` method is the one where I add an eventlistener when the drawing of the rect is done and the `adaugaClick` draws the little rectangles. What seems to be the problem that causes the click event to fire multiple times? I tried calling `e.stopPropagation();`, thinking that maybe it has something to to with this, but it didn't work

```
class BarChart {
    constructor(domElement) {

        this.domElement = domElement;
        this.svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        this.rect = document.createElementNS(this.svgns, 'rect');
    }
    draw() {
        this.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
            if (event.button === 0) {
                const rect = document.createElementNS(this.svgns, 'rect');
                //rect.setAttribute('tabindex', "1");
                let first_mouseX = event.clientX;
                let first_mouseY = event.clientY;

                const drawRect = (event) => {

                    let mouseX = event.clientX;
                    let mouseY = event.clientY;
                    const width = Math.abs(mouseX - first_mouseX);
                    const height = Math.abs(mouseY - first_mouseY);

                    if (mouseX > first_mouseX) {
                        mouseX = first_mouseX;
                    }

                    if (mouseY > first_mouseY) {
                        mouseY = first_mouseY;
                    }

                    rect.setAttribute('x', mouseX);
                    rect.setAttribute('y', mouseY);
                    rect.setAttribute('width', width);
                    rect.setAttribute('height', height);
                    rect.setAttribute('stroke', "black");
                    rect.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
                    this.rect = rect;
                    this.domElement.appendChild(rect);
                }

                const endDraw = (e) => {
                    this.domElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", drawRect);
                    this.domElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", () => endDraw(event));
                    this.rect.addEventListener("click", () => this.adaugaClick(e))

                }

                this.domElement.addEventListener("mouseup", endDraw)
                this.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", drawRect)
            }

        })
        console.dir(this.domElement)
    }

    adaugaClick(e) {
        const dreptunghi = this.creeazaSelect(e);
        for (let rect of dreptunghi)
            this.domElement.appendChild(rect);
    }

    creeazaSelect(event) {
        const forma = event.target;
        const h = "8px";
        const w = "8px";
        const widthForma = parseInt(forma.getAttribute("width"));
        const heightForma = parseInt(forma.getAttribute("height"));
        const xForma = parseInt(forma.getAttribute('x')) - parseInt(w, 10) / 2;
        const yForma = parseInt(forma.getAttribute('y')) - parseInt(w, 10) / 2;
        const dreptunghiuri = [];

        for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            const rect = document.createElementNS(this.svgns, 'rect');
            if (i === 0) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', xForma);
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma);
            }
            else if (i === 1) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', xForma + widthForma / 2);
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma);
            }
            else if (i === 2) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', (xForma + widthForma));
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma);
            }
            else if (i === 3) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', xForma);
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma + heightForma);
            }
            else if (i === 4) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', xForma + widthForma / 2);
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma + heightForma);
            }
            else if (i === 5) {
                rect.setAttribute('x', (xForma + widthForma));
                rect.setAttribute('y', yForma + heightForma);
            }

            rect.setAttribute('height', h);
            rect.setAttribute("width", w);
            rect.setAttribute('stroke', "black");
            rect.setAttribute("fill", "#00FFFF");
            dreptunghiuri.push(rect);

        }
        return dreptunghiuri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mousedown` event is firing every time you click on a `rect`. The problem arrives when, inside `endDraw`, you add an `eventListener` to `this.rect`. This makes for erratic behavior, as `this.rect` contains the last rectangle you created, which will be getting more and more `eventListener`s. You might solve this by setting `this.rect = null;` right after `this.rect.addEventListener("click", () => this.adaugaClick(e));`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it seems so obvious now.

Comment: Glad to help. You may set it as accepted if it answers the question.